# Android: PagerAdapter's setPrimaryItem() being called more than once

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Why is `PagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem()` called more than once (with the same values) after I select a new page with `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(index)` ?

Comment: Yep, I see this too, even using android-support-v13.jar it gets called twice for each page change. Though at least using a OnPageChangeListener its onPageSelected() only gets called once.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, for me it even kept calling infinitely. However, if you need something to be called once, here is a simple solution

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

      // Only refresh when primary changes
      if(lastPosition != position) {
        lastPosition = position;

        yourFunction();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why `PagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem()` gets called more than once is because of `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`
See official docs for more info:
*https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager#setOffscreenPageLimit(kotlin.Int)*